# Google Cloud Platform: How do I find an A record for a project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to set up a custom domain name for a Google Cloud Project and am very confused by the whole process.  I just need an A record, but the only way I know how to find those is by going through the steps here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/mapping-custom-domains#mapping_a_custom_domain_to_your_app

Why do I need to go through all these steps to simply get the A record for my site?  Like why do I need to verify a specific domain?  I have my own DNS and just need to point it at a specific A record.

Comment: What do you mean by "set up a custom domain name for a Google Cloud Project"? What do you want to do? On which service do you want to set your A record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Google Cloud services have a proxy load balancer in front of them call the GFE (Google Front End). In order to know which service to route a request to, the GFE uses the HTTP Host header. You need to go through that process so that Google has an internal table mapping an IP address to a custom domain (via the Host header), which then maps to a Google Cloud service.

You are required to verify ownership of a domain to prevent domain hijacking. Imagine that I decide to use `microsoft.com`. Google requires that I prove I control the domain `microsoft.com` before allowing me to create a custom domain.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer.  So to confirm, there is no way to get the A record for a Google Cloud Project site without going through the steps in that link above?

Comment: You must follow the documentation. The GFE will return an HTTP 404 error unless the domain mapping is complete. The GFEs have a set of global IP addresses that are shared for all backend services. Just using one will get you nowhere.